# Is there a way to verify that a key is equal to a value after iterating with a for-each loop

Tags: java

In an API test, my intention is to assert that headers are returned in the response payload. Using RESTassured, I have successfully collected the headers and iterate through the key-value pairs using a for-each loop. I did this:

```
//Capture all the headers from the response
Headers allheaders = response.headers();
for (Header header : allheaders)
System.out.println(header.getName() + " " +header.getValue());
```

The headers from the response payload look something like this:

```
Content-Type  text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length  2
Date  Mon, 15 Mar 2021 12:33:57 GMT
```

Now, what I want to do is to assert that a certain key is present and it is equal to a certain value e.g.`Content-Type` isEqual `to text/plain;charset=UTF-8`, but not sure how to resolve it. There are 3 key-value pairs and I am not sure how to get the index of a pair and so that I can verify that the key is equal to the corresponding value. Any ideas?

Comment: `if name.equals ('whatever') && value.equals ('myValue') return true`

Comment: What if I want to use an `assertThat` for verification?

Comment: What have you tried? What is wrong with what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

Optional header = allHeaders.stream().filter(h -> Objects.equals("expected", h.getName()).findAny().get();
assertTrue(header.isPresent());

Comment: Thanks, Dori. This will fetch and verify the header. How can the header be checked to be equal to an expected value?

Answer (score 1):

If you think you will be using this a lot, first, create a matcher for your headers:

```java
class HeaderMatcher extends BaseMatcher<Header> {
    private final String key;
    private final String value;

    // Returns a new matcher based on the expected parameters
    public static HeaderMatcher ofKeyAndValue(String key, String value) {
        return new HeaderMatcher(key, value);
    }

    public HeaderMatcher(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // Does the actual matching
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object item) {
        if (item instanceof Header) {
            final Header header = (Header) item;
            return key.equals(header.name) &&
                    value.equals(header.value);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use that matcher wherever Hamcrest matchers are accepted:

```java
assertThat(headerList, CoreMatchers.hasItem(ofKeyAndValue("key", "value")));
assertThat(header, CoreMatchers.is(ofKeyAndValue("key", "value")));
```